# How can I help my cat throw up a stuck hairball?

Tags: cats, medicines, veterinarian

Lots of detail below, but here's the main question: **Assuming that a cat has a large hairball and is repeatedly trying to throw it up but failing, and assuming that laxatives have been used but not succeeded, what options are there to help the cat vomit up the hairball?**

Way more detail:

Jack is an orange tabby rescue, about two years old. I've had him for about his whole life. Historically he has sometimes (once every couple weeks) made a wheezing sound as though he was going to vomit up a hairball, but then expelled nothing, often swallowing at the end. He has never thrown up a hairball in these two years. I assumed hair was being expelled in feces, so I wasn't worried.

Jack is very overweight. He clocks in at 18 pounds. My other cat, a male, two year-old Bombay rescue, has the same diet and exercise but is a healthy weight.

Three and a half days ago Jack started repeatedly (several times an hour) retching loudly, as though he was trying to vomit a hairball and failing. I took him in for a veterinary appointment about 24 hours after this began (earliest I could get). The vet couldn't discover evidence of a blockage and I reported that Jack was still eating, drinking, urinating, and defecating, so the vet gave me Amoxicillin for Jack (in case the sound was actually an upper respiratory infection) and laxative paste (in case it was a hairball). I've been using these faithfully since receiving them.

Jack did indeed vomit one hairball up later on Saturday, the first I've ever seen, but it was only a normal size where I was expecting something huge. After this Jack's retching reduced to about once an hour, a third of the frequency it had been previously, but it did not stop. Jack seems to me to be tired or lethargic and to be unhappy. He's less prone to purr and I think he's eating less, but he definitely is still eating. Fat aside, he seems bloated to me. I'm planning to take him back to the vet for an x-ray asap.

I have more than enough money for surgery if he needs it, but I would very much like to avoid putting him through that if at all possible.

Comment: It sounds like your mind is set on the "giant hairball too big to vomit" theory, but it could be a stomach flu or gastritis or something completely different as well. As long as his condition doesn't deteriorate, wait for a thorough examination by the vet. In the future, provide a flower pot with grass if they are exclusively indoors.

Comment: Well, I'm planning to take him in for an x-ray. That should reveal whether or not he has a mass consistent with a large hairball. If he does then I still need a solution and I'm still hoping to avoid surgery, so I'm still trying to get other options for that specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If there’s no medical condition that’s causing Jack’s problem, some of the preventative remedies found [on this page](https://canidae.com/blog/9-surprising-home-remedies-for-your-cats-hairballs) may work for you. There’s no way for anybody to diagnose this problem from afar.

The most important is to brush Jack, if he lets you, that is. This helps remove fur that would otherwise fall to the ground or get ingested. It also stimulates and reinforces the bond between you. This doesn’t work for every cat, though.

Next is a small amount of olive oil in their food every few days. I’ve never tried butter, only because cats are somewhat lactose-intolerant, and I don’t want to cause problems at the other end of the cat, if you get my drift.

A dab of petroleum jelly on a paw works, too.

Comment: There are flavored petroleum jelly mixtures sold specifically as hairball remedies, which may or may not be easier to get the cat to cooperate with. (My siamese was reluctant to lick the stuff even so.) There are also some foods which claim to reduce hairball frequency. Growing a pot of a suitable grass for the cat to nibble at may also help; pet stores will be glad to sell you seeds. But, yes, the more loose fur you groom off the cat, the less it has to groom off itself, and many cats do enjoy the attention.